# Bug: possible logic flaw in the review auditing system

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

**Hypothesis**

Stackoverflow contains some automated review auditing logic. The goal is to ensure that reviewers are paying attention and not blindly accepting content without critical scrutiny.

The logic implemented to reach this goal is flawed however, because it incorrectly identifies favorable reviewer performance as unfavorable in situations when the reviewer has a relatively high accept/reject ratio.

**Problem**

A reviewer with more than zero successful rejections of vandalism (where success is defined as receiving a **'congratulations, you passed the test'** message) is exhibiting favorable reviewer performance.

However, it is possible to have more than zero successful rejections of vandalism while still getting suspended from doing reviews, because the review auditing logic appears to place **inappropriate importance on the accept/reject ratio**.

If a reviewer exhibiting favorable reviewer performance **chooses to skip (instead of reject) questionable content**, this reviewer will get a higher accept/reject ratio, and consequently run the risk of being negatively affected by this logic flaw.

**Steps to reproduce**

- begin moderation on one or more review items
- successfully reject one or more vandalism and defacement posts (questionable content)
- repeat the previous two steps for span of (??) days
- at a later time, modify your review strategy to "Skip" instead of "Reject" questionable content
- accept all content that appears credible, and skip all questionable content
- repeat using the new modified review strategy for a span of (??) days
- accept a post that is borderline acceptable (e.g., the content is not clearly vandalism, but instead appears to be a clarification or attempt to comment or reply to an existing post)
- the outcome will be a suspension from review for (??) days (see included image below)

[image]

**Conclusion**

If the above hypothesis is correct, the review auditing logic inappropriately assumes that a high accept/reject ratio reflects an uncritical review of content. Based on the facts and background provided in this example, that assumption seems flawed.

**Proposed solution**

Either remove the ability to "Skip" questionable content, thus forcing the reviewer to maintain a certain accept/reject ratio that is consistent with expectations, OR re-calibrate the way accept/reject ratio is used to determine unacceptable reviewer performance.

Comment: Note: This post got down-voted almost instantaneously after being posted, faster than it would take an average human to actually read it. This is rather curious. Is someone out there trying to send a message?

Comment: Everytime I read moderator in your post I have to adapt because you mean reviewer, I assume? And a second question: you are review banned right now?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, the terms reviewer and moderator were used interchangeably, admittedly this is not precise, an edit will be done to improve this.

Yes, currently a suspension from reviews is in place on this account, consistent with the image.

Comment: Looking through your last several reviews you approved several very minor edits and several radical changes/edits that should have been comments.  Clearly this review ban is appropriate, and you need to take some time to reflect on your reviews.

Comment: Have you check out the example in the message? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4694367 IMO, that should be rejected.

Comment: I guess it should be rejected *on principle* - but it does seem to make the answer more complete.  Specifically, it's the *asker* of the question "completing" an almost working answer to the form which actually works.  Most likely that should be a comment, though the result would be a less immediately readable solution.  I'd be really interested to know if @dreftymac made the disputed call from the brief principle-only review page, or after clicking through to the post itself and examining it in context.

Comment: **// Clearly this review ban is appropriate, and you need to take some time to reflect on your reviews//** This may or may not be accurate, however **the ban only gives one review as substantiation**, and it is not unambiguously clear why that constitutes **"defacement"**.

Nevertheless, the legitimacy of the ban is not of concern to the OP. It is enough to know that the flaw is not in the logic of the auditing system itself, but rather human intervention. That was the primary purpose of the inquiry.

Comment: You've also approved other things that really shouldn't have. I went through the first two pages of your reviews and found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4701587) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4694367), for example. Don't make it look like you're getting something you don't deserve.

Comment: **//Don't make it look like you're getting something you don't deserve//** This is off-topic and unhelpful because it assumes personal motives.

Moreover it provides zero clarification for the claim of **"defacement"**.

Generally speaking, it is a well known principle in nearly every profession to identify unfavorable performance by giving **specific guidance** on how such performance can be improved.

Moreover, it was already plainly stated that the goal was to determine a possible flaw in the automated logic. It is now clear the problem(s) (if any) were based on human action.

Comment: "identify unfavorable performance by giving specific guidance on how such performance can be improved" next time you see an edit like that, reject it ;).

Comment: @Braiam: **//next time you see an edit like that, reject it ;)//** It does not explain or justify the claim of **defacement**. Perhaps the winky is admission of this fact, in which case thanks for the attempt to inject some humor. Humor and wit is fine, but that does not enhance the professionalism or propriety of the unsubstantiated claim. Nevertheless, feel free to enjoy yourself, nothing wrong with a little humor.

Answer (score 28):

You were not banned automatically.  A very human moderator banned you and gave you that message because he felt that you were not doing your job effectively, particularly in the case of the example shown.

This has nothing to do with audits.  You were not banned for failing them, you were banned because the very human moderator recognized you inappropriately handling real, non-audit, reviews.

Comment: That's good to know. That also helps provide additional context for the near-instantaneous down-vote that appeared on this inquiry [faster than the reading speed of most humans]. Ironic. 

**//the very human moderator recognized you inappropriately handling real, non-audit, reviews//**

This [review(s) plural] appears to be inaccurate, since only one review was given as substantiation.

Comment: @dreftymac What do you mean "since only one review was given as substantiation"? Where do you see a specific review given as evidence of your review ban?

Comment: @dreftymac Ah, I see what you meant now. I think it's clear from that message that the moderator though multiple edits were improper, but you're correct that there's only one link, so I understand.

Comment: @dreftymac notice that [Undo provided more examples about improper approvals.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253156/bug-possible-logic-flaw-in-the-review-auditing-system#comment12137_253156) I presume the moderator has a character limit and can't possibly point to all the bad revisions.

Comment: @Braiam: **//notice that Undo provided more examples about improper approvals//** That is actually not correct. The first link is redundant of the original ban, and neither contains explanation of any impropriety or defacement.

Moreover, contesting the appropriateness of the ban was not the primary purpose of this post. Those who are defensive about it are defensive for their own reasons.

Comment: @drefty I think that "defacement" was a poor word choice.  That implies (to me) something like replacing all the text of the answer with "sjrbe37$wjd$;3+7hs" or "ha ha this is so gay."   However, the review linked in the ban message is still a good example of an edit that should be rejected.  It's modifying the meaning (to some extent) of an accepted answer, which is frowned upon (you can search on Meta Stack Exchange about that topic - I'm on mobile or I'd link you to something).  The asker accepted that answer the way it was for a reason.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Many thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @dreftymac If you want a more detailed explanation of why the actions you've taken are improper then *ask for it*.  If you seriously don't know why [approving blatant vandalism](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4492863) is wrong, then you can ask, and we can help you.  A detailed explanation of why so many of your reviews wasn't given was that so many of these actions are *obviously* wrong to us, and Brad and I didn't actually expect you to be unaware of why these actions are wrong.

Comment: If you're just looking to argue, I have no interest, but if you sincerely don't know why what you did was wrong, and are looking for help understanding how to review properly, then *politely and constructively ask for help*.  That's what this review ban is here to give you the opportunity to do; to learn from your mistakes.  If you want to continue using the system, then utilize that opportunity.

Comment: @Servy **//If you seriously don't know why approving blatant vandalism is wrong//** This is not at issue. The link you just posted is readily acknowledged as a poor review and it was not linked nor referenced as rationale for the suspension.

Comment: @Servy **//so many of these actions are obviously wrong to us//** You've provided a **single** link to review that is openly acknowledged as bad. If that were the only issue there would be nothing to contest or complain about. The problem is **the rationale for the ban contains a blatant and unambiguous factual error that does not acknowledge my improvement**, nor my successful rejection of unacceptable content.

Comment: @dreftymac The review ban content is limited in space.  A simple, abridged explanation was given because it was expected that you would know what you did wrong when informed *that* you did something wrong.  If you seriously are not aware of the inappropriate actions that you've taken, you're more than welcome to ask for further clarification on what you have done wrong.  You've gotten plenty of that here in this meta question.  There are simply too many bad reviewers and too few that care about being banned to spend an hour explaining to each one what they did wrong and how to improve.

Comment: @Servy **// If you seriously are not aware of the inappropriate actions that you've taken//** The mistaken acceptance of a single post that contained vandalism (from a month ago) was already acknowledged. Moreover this single post was not even mentioned until today. Other than that, there do not appear to be any (unambiguous) mistakes in my review history. Moreover (as stated previously) the ban rationale **does** contain an unambiguous mistake, which has been conceded by the person who took credit for the ban.

Comment: @dreftymac So far there have been *several* inappropriate reviews linked to you in this thread alone.  If you *really* want some more, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4696013, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4695988, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4696007, and http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4695021.  And those are all just from your most recent page of reviews, that's not going back any further than that.

Comment: @Servy As stated previously, **none of those links contain unambiguously mistaken acceptances of defacement or vandalism**, which is the rationale that was given in the suspension. In this context, your definition of "inappropriate" is therefore vague. If you can precisely define "inappropriate" that would be helpful. Otherwise, it seems reasonable to conclude that reasonable people can disagree, and point out (again) that the ban rationale contains a **mistaken assumption that is demonstrably false**.

Comment: @dreftymac So you know you have a whole mess of inappropriate approvals of posts, you're just mad at the use of the word "vandalism" despite the fact that at least some of the approvals you've made *are* vandalism, although many are other types of inappropriate edits?  In that case, you still know that what you did was wrong.  Take some time to reflect on it.  Focus on what you need to do in order to not approve inappropriate edits in the future.  Don't focus so much on your ban wording, because you clearly know that your ban is deserved.  Having its wording changed now helps no one.

Comment: @Servy **//you're just mad at the use of the word "vandalism"//** Who said anyone is mad? The purpose is to maintain the high quality of content on the site, period. Everyone can agree that vandalism is unacceptable and inappropriate. I've happily conceded that I mistakenly accepted a **single** post that was vandalism.

Comment: @dreftymac You've accepted more than just one vandalism edit.  You were review banned recently, according to Brad.  That requires *several* failed audits, not just one.  And the fact that you're trying **so** hard to avoid taking responsibility for your numerous mistakes, instead attacking the people informing you of what you've done wrong to attempt to draw attention away from your *very numerous* abuses of the system, tells me that you're very clearly not ready to be reviewing posts.  A 7 day ban may well have been too short for you.  If only I was a mod capable of extending it.

Comment: @dreftymac Non-moderators cannot easily find all failed audits, so I'm not going to take the time to look through your entire history to find them all, but as you know you were review banned, you know that there were several recent failed audits.  At this point it's obvious to everyone, including you, that you've done wrong.  You know it, and you're still just looking to argue for the sake of arguing, not argue for the sake of improving, so I see no need to reply further.  You now know what you've done wrong.  Either learn, and improve, or just stop reviewing.  It's your choice.

Comment: @Servy **//At this point it's obvious to everyone, including you, that you've done wrong.//** Likewise, **the suspension rationale** contains an assumption that is **demonstrably incorrect**, and has been proven **false**. Other than a mistake made (a month ago) there does not appear to be any (unambiguous) cases of wrongdoing at issue in this discussion. Feel free to point them out if you find any, and thanks for continuing along with me and others to contribute to the high-quality of SO.

Comment: @dreftymac No, the explanation is *not* demonstrably incorrect.  You do *appear* to be approving everything you see.  Even if you are not in fact approving everything, you do in fact *appear* to be.  And if you are not approving everything, you are still demonstrably approving a *lot* of things that you shouldn't be.  If you are seriously ignoring all of the wrongdoing that you've been presented with here, then clearly you are in no shape to continue reviewing.

Comment: @Servy **// Even if you are not in fact approving everything, you do in fact appear to be//** This is a self-contradictory statement. **This "appearance" is not consistent with unambiguous and directly observable evidence to the contrary.** **(Proof)** stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4680800 stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4650621 stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4573725 stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4033369

Comment: @dreftymac He did not say, "you are approving everything you see".  He said you appear to be, because you *do* appear to be.  The fact that you rejected a few edits a long time ago doesn't change that.  *Right now* you *appeared* to be approving everything to him.  And regardless, it's a pointless discussion to have.  You were reviewing inappropriately.  You know you were reviewing inappropriately.  If you didn't know then (which I highly doubt) then you do now, so future discussion of the topic is only wasting everyone's time.  Brad did *nothing* wrong in banning you.

Comment: **// He said you appear to be, because you do appear to be//** This "appearance" is inconsistent with observable evidence to the contrary. Intellectual honesty in any realm of research includes the willingness to admit when an assumption is not consistent with observable evidence. (Such as this) stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4680800 stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4650621 stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4573725 stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4033369

Comment: @dreftymac Congradulations, you rejected four edits.  Well done.  Come back when you're ready to review properly and not approve edits that you shouldn't be approving.

Comment: **//Congradulations, you rejected four edits.//** Thanks. Congradulations [sic] likewise to you, for admitting that the ban rationale contained an assumption inconsistent with the facts. Also, thanks for your continued participation on SO and MSO, and for doing your part along with me to improve the quality of the site.

Comment: @dreftymac I made no such admission.  In fact, I specifically stated otherwise, repeatedly.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the clarification. You've acknowledged that there is a non-zero number of successful rejections. That's more than enough to substantiate the point. Thanks again for your participation.

Comment: @dreftymac So, are you ready to review properly now, or do you still intend to approve inappropriate edits when your ban ends?

Comment: @Servy If you wish to discuss anything about me personally, I am more than happy to initiate a chat session or interaction through e-mail.  You've acknowledged that there is a non-zero number of successful rejections. That's more than enough to substantiate the point.

Comment: @dreftymac I'll take that as a no.  I look forward to your next review ban.  I'll make a point of checking up on you and reminding the moderators to ban you again when you continue to abuse the system.

Comment: @Servy You've misrepresented my reply. As a basic rule of interaction, I assume goodwill on the part of all participants in this forum, and assume everyone is here to improve the quality of the site, as well as improve their own level of participation.  If you wish to discuss anything about me personally, I am more than happy to initiate a chat session or interaction through e-mail. You've acknowledged that there is a non-zero number of successful rejections. That's more than enough to substantiate the point.

Comment: @Servy **// I'll take that as a no. I look forward to your next review ban.//** That's curious. It would be more encouraging to hear you look forward to helping contributors improve the quality of the site. If you have a personal issue with me or animosity, please feel free to initiate a chat session. I look forward to reconciling any personal differences or disagreements.

Answer (score 21):

As has been stated, you were not banned by the system automatically this time. I manually banned you from review after you were flagged for approving a series of bad edits. I only felt the need to point to [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4694367) that obviously should not have been approved. I believe that my use of "defaced" is proper there, in that incorrect wording was appended to an answer and that edit was correctly rejected by others.

If you would like another example of a poor review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4695988

I gave you a 7-day ban because you had just come off a 2-day review ban triggered by failing suggested edit audits, such as this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4492863

Suggested edit audits should never be approved under any circumstances.

You'll pardon my use of "blindly accepting every edit" when I see approvals like that, coupled with a recent review history that [looks like this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42223/dreftymac?tab=activity). In fact, the only edits you appear to have rejected are recent audits, and some people have been known to game this, so I look carefully at anyone whose only rejections are audits.

Please don't approve edits like this in the future.

Comment: //the only edits you appear to have rejected are recent audits//

As stated in the OP, ***this rationale does not take into account reviewers who adopt a strategy of "skipping" instead of "rejecting" questionable content***. Therefore, your claims of "obviousness" seems contestable.

Nevertheless, even if the review in question did not meet your standards, it seems fair to point out that ***you concede your stated rationale contains a factual error***, which I am happy to pardon, and leave it at that.

Thank you for sharing your opinions, and for your participation on Stackoverflow.

Comment: //the only edits you appear to have rejected are recent audits// Just for the sake of emphasis, **successfully rejecting audits is precisely the kind of evidence that demonstrates the reviewer is paying attention and is not a bot.** This is not a criticism of your efforts, but please feel free to consider that **a high accept/reject ratio is not a sufficient basis for concluding the reviewer is not paying close attention.**

Comment: Since this is meta., it seems appropriate to go meta here. This whole debate is fascinating to me. Drefty seems obsessed with the technical accuracy of the ban *reason*. The rest of the comments make clear that bans are not automatic, and ban reasons are canned bits of text. There is no "algorithm" to fix. I think the point here is *if you have the sort of personality that fixates on the technical accuracy of a (canned, multiple-choice) stated reason for a ban rather than on the underlying reasons for the ban, then you're going to have a bad time.*

Comment: @AndrewS: Many (probably even most) bans are automatic.  This particular one, though,  was not; in this case, the user's review history was bad enough to attract attention, but rejecting just the right edits kept it from triggering the automated ban.  So a human intervened.

Comment: @AndrewS: I do agree, though, that it's a bit silly to focus on the wording of the reason, rather than the actual *reason*.  You don't get review-banned for one bad review, but for a *history* or *pattern* of them.  By the time there's even a ban to contest, there's a growing pile of evidence that the bannee is not doing what they implicitly agreed to do.